# CSS Wordpress Menu

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I seem to be having a problem with my Wordpress CSS Menu. I am trying to create a dropdown element in the menu, which is conveniently wrapped in a div automatically called "sub-menu".

When normal, the menu looks like this:
[image: normal menu]

However, when I try to access the drop-down menu under "Photography", this happens:



[image]

I have tried everything and am unable to get it to correctly show up under Photography. Any help would be much appreciated:

```
#header li ul.sub-menu {
display:none;
position: absolute;
top: 10px;
left: 50%;
width: auto;
}

#header li:hover ul.sub-menu {
display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure the container element (#header li) is set to a position as well. I would use relative becasue it will (hopefully) not break other positioning:

```
#header li {
position: relative;
}

#header li ul.sub-menu {
display:none;
position: absolute;
top: 10px;
left: 50%;
width: auto;
}

header li:hover ul.sub-menu {
display:block;
}
```

Absolute elements will position itself based on the nearest parent who's position is set explicitly.